# Database id column or code column

Tags: c#, database-design

I am working on a project where I have to implement some new functionality. 
In the process I have to design some tables and build some editors for that data.
I have one table for categories and one for types.

On client side I have to build some lists using those types, but each list must use types from only one category.
I don't like the idea to use PKs in my C#. I would rather create a column name "Code" in the category table and use that in my C# code, when preparing the lists.

**EDIT**: I do not mean removing the PK (I will have an int base Id column). I mean adding another column to the category ("Code") to use jsut in C# as string constants, instead of ids.

Is this an okay idea?

Comment: I think you should always have primary-foreign key relationships between your database tables, assuming the DB supports it and it makes sense for them to be there.

Comment: *Is this an okay idea?* go ahead and implement the way you posted ... if you face issue down the line which mostly you will ... you will understand that it's NOT a good idea

Comment: If the data elements are logically related, it is always a good idea to relate them with primary key-foreign keys relationships and appropriate cascading logic supported by your DB. You may possibly introduce a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) to keep the DB sane and at the same time using some 'code' that makes sense to the business on the client side.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please see my edit. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question, I would recommend the following structure for your tables:

```
Table Category
    ID Int                     -- primary key
    Code Varchar(8)            -- Code value displayed to users
    Description Varchar(100)


Table Item
    ID Int                     -- primary key
    CategoryID Int             -- foreign key to Category
    Code Varchar(8)            -- Code value displayed to users
    Description Varchar(100)
```

This way, if you change a Category record's Code, nothing changes behind the scenes, and the key values are never exposed to your users.